# The sum of the total number of service representatives who spoke with all the customers who called during a minute.

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I trying to solve this problem, but I can not tell if what I am doing is right,

> At some company, the customer support department gets called by $5$ customers per minute independently.
>
> The number of service representatives that are needed to be called until a customer problem is solved is $X∼G(0.4)$ for every customer independently.
>
> Let $A$ be the sum of the total number of service representatives who spoke with all the customers who called during a minute.
>
> Find $Pr⁡[A≤3]$.

My attempt:

Let $Y\sim \mathrm{Pois}(5)$ be the number of customers calling per minute.

$Pr[A\le 3]=Pr[A=0]+Pr[A=1]+Pr[A=2]+Pr[A=3]$.

- $Pr[A=0]=Pr[Y=0]$
- $Pr[A=1]=Pr[Y=1]\cdot Pr[X=1]$
- $Pr[A=2]=Pr[Y=2]\cdot Pr[X=1] + Pr[Y=1]\cdot Pr[X=2]$
- $Pr[A=3]=Pr[Y=3]\cdot Pr[X=1] + Pr[Y=2]\cdot (Pr[X=1] + Pr[X=2]) + Pr[Y=1]\cdot Pr[X=3]$

Notes:

- I intentionally did not expand $Pr[X=i]$ and $Pr[X=j]$ to its
  numeric to keep things simple.
- I am most unsure about $Pr[A=3]$.

Comment: What distribution is G(0.4)

Comment: Geometric Distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mean number of service representatives required to solve a customer problem $=\frac{1}{.4} = 2.5$

Number of customers per minute =$ 5$

Thus mean number of total service representatives $= 5\times 2.5=12.5$

$P(A\le 3) = \sum_{t=0}^{t=3}\frac{e^{-12.5}.(12.5)^{t}}{t!}=0.001555$

Comment: Can you tell why my solution is not valid? it seems logically correct.

Comment: I know that it is not correct, but I want to know why.

Comment: Meshing these two distributions like what you have mentioned is intractable and complicated.  It might sound logical but is not right.  Think of how you will calculate each of these pieces in your solution?

Comment: It took me a while, but I understand now.